# Are woocommerce questions not allowed wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

One of my questions was put on hold [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348775/extra-checkbox-price-added-on-top-of-variable-prices-selected-through-drop-down?noredirect=1#comment510221_348775). stating that woocommerce questions are off-topic.

But there are many questions(not asked by me) that were allowed.
[Take this for example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312231/woocommerce-change-price-in-cart)

If the above is true(woocommerce being a third party plugin not allowed) why there is a tag of **woocommerce** in wordpress.stackexchange.com

I am not **cynical** against anyone nor **prejudiced**, but want to know the truth. I am a serious contributor and was never a casual poster.

Is not the whole objective is helping each other from across the globe.

If woocommerce questions are not allowed then woocommerce tag should be officially removed.

Comment: I would not that just because a Q hasn't been closed doesn't mean it's on topic or was allowed. This assumes a perfect filter and that all questions were seen and processed. I've never seen that particular question you used as an example, but it is indeed offtopic, and I've closed it. I'm sure you'll be able to find other examples of open WooCommerce questions if you look, that doesn't mean they were allowed or that they were on topic though

Comment: Also see my comment on my answer to the other Q this was marked as a duplicate of for why the WooCommerce tag exists